# Connection between generators in homology and cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

For simplicity let's consider simplicial homology.

I have sometimes seen in books, how having $[\alpha_1],\dots, [\alpha_n]$ - generators in $H_k(X,\mathbb{Z})$ one takes $[\alpha^1],\dots, [\alpha^n]$ as generators in $H^k(X,\mathbb{Z})$, where $[\alpha^i]$ is represented by the cochain that takes value $1$ on $\alpha_i$ and $0$ 'everywhere else'. No book had an explanation though.

I have some questions:

0) What should I replace "everywhere else" with? If $\alpha_i$ is not a simplex and I write "on any other chain" I get something that is not a cochain.

1) Why does it work?

2) Does it work for $k\geq2$? It looks like this method has something to do with the universal coefficient theorem, specifically, with isomorphism $H^k=Hom(H_k,\mathbb{Z})$ for $i=0,1$, but it does not hold for greater $k$.

3) Is it true for reduced cohomology? For $k=1$ the answer perhaps is the same as for usual cohomology. However, for $k=0$ there is $\widetilde{H}^0=Hom(\widetilde{H}_0,\mathbb{Z})$, which, if this isomorphism really makes this method work, must mean that it is true.

For example, if I take simplicial complex $K$ as disjoint union of a segment $\{1,3\}$ and a point  $\{2\}$. Then $\widetilde{H}_0(K,\mathbb{Z})=H_0(K,\{3\})$ (relative homology in $RHS$) is generated by class of chain $\{2\}.$ Does it mean that $\widetilde{H}^0$ is generated by class of cochain dual to simplex $\{2\}$?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you quote a precise passage from one of these books ? Maybe it was in a case where $H_k(X)$ is free abelian for all $k$ ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I can try to find something, but yes, it is very likely that $H_k(X)=\mathbb{Z}^n$ in these examples. What can be said in this case?

Comment: Well if $H_k(X)$ and $H_{k-1}(X)$ are both free abelian, the universal coefficient theorem tells you that $Hom(H_k(X),\mathbb Z) \cong H^k(X)$ actually holds; so you can use that to see that the statement makes sense

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Ok, so I get that for any $[\alpha]$ generator in $H_k$ there is $[\alpha]^*$ generator in cohomology. What I want to know is cochain $c$ such that $[c]=[\alpha]^*$. For example, if $H_k(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ then then $c$ is $1$ on $\alpha$ (and 0 on other generators? But there are no generators left), but it doesn't really define $c$. Or I can take any $c$ that is $1$ on $\alpha$?

Comment: The universal coefficient theorem tells you that in that situation there will be a (unique up to cohomology) cochain $c$ such that $c(\alpha) = 1$

Comment: @MaximeRamzi But I can't calculates $c$ on any chain?

Comment: Well any chain is $n\alpha$ up to homology, for a unique $n$, and since $c$ is a cocycle, its value on a cochain depends only on its homology class, so you can compute $c$ on any chain if you know what $n\alpha$ it is homologous to.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Oh, right! I somehow forgot that $\delta c=c \partial$. Thank you!